# Not enough space to cache rdd in memory warning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark, rdd

I am running a spark job, and I got **Not enough space to cache rdd_128_17000 in memory** warning. However, in the attached file, it obviously saying only **90.8 G out of 719.3 G** is used. Why is that? Thanks!

---

```
15/10/16 02:19:41 WARN storage.MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache rdd_128_17000 in memory! (computed 21.4 GB so far)
15/10/16 02:19:41 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Memory use = 4.1 GB (blocks) + 21.2 GB (scratch space shared across 1 thread(s)) = 25.2 GB. Storage limit = 36.0 GB.
15/10/16 02:19:44 WARN storage.MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache rdd_129_17000 in memory! (computed 9.4 GB so far)
15/10/16 02:19:44 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Memory use = 4.1 GB (blocks) + 30.6 GB (scratch space shared across 1 thread(s)) = 34.6 GB. Storage limit = 36.0 GB.
15/10/16 02:25:37 INFO metrics.MetricsSaver: 1001 MetricsLockFreeSaver 339 comitted 11 matured S3WriteBytes values
15/10/16 02:29:00 INFO s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream: uploadPart /mnt1/var/lib/hadoop/s3/959a772f-d03a-41fd-bc9d-6d5c5b9812a1-0000 134217728 bytes md5: qkQ8nlvC8COVftXkknPE3A== md5hex: aa443c9e5bc2f023957ed5e49273c4dc
15/10/16 02:38:15 INFO s3n.MultipartUploadOutputStream: uploadPart /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/s3/959a772f-d03a-41fd-bc9d-6d5c5b9812a1-0001 134217728 bytes md5: RgoGg/yJpqzjIvD5DqjCig== md5hex: 460a0683fc89a6ace322f0f90ea8c28a
15/10/16 02:42:20 INFO metrics.MetricsSaver: 2001 MetricsLockFreeSaver 339 comitted 10 matured S3WriteBytes values
```

[image]

Comment: Total used / Total does not matter for caching blocks, they are atomic in memory sense. Can you try to increase # of partitions for that specific RDD? BTW, you have a nifty cluster.

Comment: So what would be the difference between caching block and the (Total used/Total) appeared on UI? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This is likely to be caused by the configuration of `spark.storage.memoryFraction` being too low. Spark will only use this fraction of the allocated memory to cache RDDs.

Try either:

- increasing the storage fraction
- `rdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER)` to reduce memory usage by serializing the RDD data
- `rdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)` to partially persist onto disk if memory limits are reached.

Comment: I found this blog post very useful in order to better understand this configuration: https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the following issue if you're loading lots of avro files:

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201510.mbox/%3CCANx3uAiJqO4qcTXePrUofKhO3N9UbQDJgNQXPYGZ14PWgfG5Aw@mail.gmail.com%3E

With a PR in progress at:

https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/pull/95

Answer (score 0):

I have a Spark-based batch application (a JAR with `main()` method, not written by me, I'm not a Spark expert) that I run in local mode without `spark-submit`, `spark-shell`, or `spark-defaults.conf`.  When I tried to use IBM JRE (like one of my customers) instead of Oracle JRE (same machine and same data), I started getting those warnings.

Since the memory store is a fraction of the heap (see [the page](https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/) that Jacob suggested in his comment), I checked the heap size: IBM JRE uses a different strategy to decide [default heap size](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/8?topic=options-xms) and it was too small, so I simply added appropriate `-Xms` and `-Xmx` params and the problem disappeared: now the batch works fine both with IBM and Oracle JRE.

My usage scenario is not typical, I know, however I hope this can help someone.